# Parallel downloading of JS files in HTML

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, asynchronous, resource-timing-api

I have an HTML file which looks like this

```
 <html>
    <head>
        <script src="1.js"></script>
        <script src="2.js"></script>
        ...
        <script src="200.js"></script>
    </head>
 </html>
```

1.js contains just one line

```
window.performance.setResourceTimingBufferSize(250);
```

By default, the resource buffer size in Chrome is 150.

But, when I see all the resources using Resource Timing API, the length of resources is not 200. It keeps varying randomly between 150 to 200.

I know why this is happening. Because, Chrome tries to download the resources in parallel and hence, it registers the resources in Resource Timing API.

The snippet in 1.js

```
window.performance.setResourceTimingBufferSize(250);
```

actually gets executed a bit later. Hence, some more resources get added to resource timing buffer. But, not all of them are added.

Is there a way to stop the parallel download of resources? Download the first resource first, let the code execute and then resume downloading of the remaining resources in parallel.

Comment: Why would you load 200 different JS sources ? I think by default, the scripts are loaded synchronously.

Comment: It's not about JS sources. I can have other resources too, like images, css etc. The scripts are executed synchronously, but I think they are downloaded in parallel. Modern browsers do so in order to be efficient.

Comment: Yes, but I can't think of anything to solve the problem. I think you should try to reduce the number of sources you load. Combine them, or don't load them all at the same time.

Comment: @skjindal93 I don't think there's an way to make them being downloaded sequentially. Browser's job is to display the content asap. Hence, when a <script> for external JS blocks the DOM engine, a secondary light-weight DOM parser scans the following code and pushes the found resources -- JS/images/... to download queue, with priorities for each of them. Intent -- get CRP (Critical Rendering Path) done asap.

Comment: @skjindal93 However, I find that when there are sequential non-async external JS files exist, Chrome is downloading them sequentially (even in latest ver 57). But chrome doc says that the secondary light weight parser should help in downloading the subsequent JS file in parallel (but execute sequentially). Get to think this is some weakness with Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the [resourcetimingbufferfull event](https://www.w3.org/TR/resource-timing-1/#dom-performance-onresourcetimingbufferfull) to [setResourceTimingBufferSize](https://www.w3.org/TR/resource-timing-1/#dom-performance-setresourcetimingbuffersize). It is said *no PerformanceResourceTiming objects are to be removed from the performance entry buffer*.

```
var buffSize = 100

if (window.performance && window.performance.addEventListener) window.performance.addEventListener('resourcetimingbufferfull', function(){
  buffSize += 100
  window.performance.setResourceTimingBufferSize(buffSize);
})
```

When buffer gets full it increments by +100